# Telerik rad grid combo box event

Tags: telerik, radgrid

I m using telerik rad grid

I have used combo box to display company Type.

If company Type is ABC than **Design Firm type should not be displayed**

how to write code on combobox in telerik radgrid ![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to take two steps to make this work.  First, set up an [EditForm Template](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/dataediting/templateformupdate/defaultcs.aspx) in your `RadGrid`.  Next, you'll need to use related `RadComboBoxes` (as shown in [this example](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/multiplecomboboxes/defaultcs.aspx)) to achieve your desired functionality.

EditForm Template example code

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="ContactTitle" HeaderText="ContactTitle">           
     <EditItemTemplate>    
         <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox1" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("CountryID") %>' DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="CountryID"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged">               
         </telerik:RadComboBox>             
     </EditItemTemplate>    
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>    

<telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="TemplateColumn">    
     <EditItemTemplate>    
         <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox2"  runat="server">    
         </telerik:RadComboBox>    
     </EditItemTemplate>    
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Cascading ComboBox example

```
protected void RadComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object o, RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)    
    {    
        RadComboBox rdcbx = (RadComboBox)o;    
        GridEditableItem editedItem = rdcbx.NamingContainer as GridEditableItem;    
        RadComboBox ddList = editedItem.FindControl("RadComboBox2") as RadComboBox;    
        // change the data source for ddList here    
         .....           
    }
```

[source](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/cascading-dropdown-or-radcombobox-in-radgrid-popup-mode.aspx)